# lsqcurvefit when expecting small coefficients

Tags: rounding, curve-fitting

I've generated a plot of the attenutation seen in an electrical trace up to a frequency of 14e10 rad/s. The ydata ranges from approximately 1-10 Np/m. I'm trying to generate a fit of the form

y = A*sqrt(x) + B*x + C*x^2.

I *expect* A to be around 10^-6, B to be around 10^-11, and C to be around 10^-23. However, the smallest coefficient lsqcurvefit will return is 10^-7. Also, its will only return a nonzero coefficient for A, while returning 0 for B and C. The fit actually looks really good however the physics indicates that B and C should not be 0.

Here is how I'm calling the function

```
% measurement estimate
x_alpha = [1e-6 1e-11 1e-23];

lb = [1e-7, 1e-13, 1e-25];
ub = [1e-3, 1e-6, 1e-15];
x_alpha = lsqcurvefit(@modelfun, x_alpha, omega, alpha_t, lb,ub)
```

Here is the model function

```
function [ yhat ] = modelfun( x, xdata )

yhat = x(1)*xdata.^.5 + x(2)*xdata + x(3)*xdata.^2;
end
```

Is it possible to get lsqcurvefit to return such small coefficients? Is the error in rounding or is it something else? Any ways I can change the tolerance to see a fit closer to what I expect?

Answer (score 0):

Found a stackoverflow page that seems to address this issue!

[fit using lsqcurvefit](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282864/fit-using-lsqcurvefit?rq=1)