# Denormalize results of curve fit on normalized data

Tags: matlab, normalization, curve-fitting, denormalization

I am fitting an exponential decay function with `lsqvurcefit` in *Matlab*. To do this I first [normalize](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_score#Standardizing_in_mathematical_statistics) my data because they differ several orders of magnitude. However Im not sure how to denormalize my fitted parameters.

My fitting model is `s = O + A * exp(-t/T)` where t and s are known and t is in the order of 10^-3 and s in the order of 10^5. So I subtract from them their mean and divide them by their standarddeviation. My goal is to find the best A, O and T that at the given times t will result most near s. However I dont know how to denormalize my resulting A O and T.

Might somebody know how to do this? I only found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14282864/fit-using-lsqcurvefit) question on SO about normalisation, but does not really address the same problem.

Comment: I don't think you want to normalize to begin with. That question you linked to would indicate that you want to normalize your `A`, `O` and `t`. However normalizing your `t` and `f` is like normalizing their `x` and `value` which doesn't make much sense

Comment: Maybe Im not explaining my problem right, I changed my formulation in the question.

Comment: ok see my edit on my solution. You should only denormalize your model output, but *normalize* the input (`t`) before running the model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you normalize, you must record the means and standard deviations for each of your featuers. Then you can easily use those values to denormalize.

e.g.

```
A = [1 4 7 2 9]';
B = 100 475 989 177 399]';
```

So you could just normalize right away:

```
An = (A - mean(A)) / std(A)
```

but then you can't get back to the original A. So first save the means and stds.

```
Am = mean(A); Bm = mean(B);
As = std(A);  Bs = std(B);
An = (A - Am)/As;
Bn = (B - Bm)/Bs;
```

now do whatever processing you want and then to denormalize:

```
Ad = An*As + Am;
Bd = Bn*Bs + Bm;
```

I'm sure you can see that that's going to be an issue if you have a lot of features (i.e. you have to type code out for each feature, what a mission!) so lets assume your data is arranged as a matrix, `data`, where each sample is a row and each column is a feature. Now you can do it like this:

```
data = [A, B]

means = mean(data);
stds = std(data);

datanorm = bsxfun(@rdivide, bsxfun(@minus, data, means), stds);

%// Do processing on datanorm

datadenorm = bsxfun(@plus, bsxfun(@times, datanorm, stds), means);
```

**EDIT:**

After you have fit your model parameters (`A`,`O` and `T`) using normalized `t` and `f`  then your model will expect normalized inputs and produce normalized outputs. So to use it you should first *normalize* `t` and then *denormalize* `f`.

So to find a new `f` by running the model on a normalized new `t`. So `f(tn)` where `tn = (t - tm)/ts` and `tm` is the mean of your training (or fitting) `t` set and `ts` the std. Then to get your correct magnitude f you must denormalize only f, so the full solution would be

```
 f(tn)*fs + fm
```

So once again, all you need to do is save the mean and std you used to normalize.

Comment: Well yeah but you denormalize the parameters that you normalized (in my case t and f), but I want to denormalize my fitted (new and different A O T) parameters

Comment: @Leo oh - it is usual to normalize inputs if you have many inputs that differ in order of magnitudes. If you input and output differ then I don't think you should be normalizing to begin with. so if you have f(A, t) where A is a vector and t is a vector then you can normalize / denormalize A and t as I have shown. But if A is a constant, and you are trying to normalize t and f... well that's very unusual and I don't think you should do it. I think in your case you should not be normalizing as that is not what it's for. The magnitude difference is due to your function, so it needs to be there.

Comment: My fitting of the function outputs the three numbers A O and T (so they dont match 1 to 1 with f and t, to which they are fitted). Because they are fitted to normalised data they will not result in f if applied to my function at given times t. For them to do that they would need to be denormalized first, thats why it does make sense. If I dont normalize the lsqcurvefit slowly zigzags into the gradient never really reaching the least error (because the gradient is so stretched by the orders of magnitude difference).

Comment: @Leo ok in that you are right to normalize. I'll edit my answer