# How to scale data before fitting in matlab 2016b

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting, data-fitting

I use the `fit()` function of matlab 2016b to fit a complicate exponential function to data `x`,`y`. 
The x values are very small (1e-3) and the y values are in the order of 1.

The fitting works well, if I multiply x by a constant factor 1000 to 100000.
This effect is described in the [mathworks online help](https://de.mathworks.com/help/curvefit/parametric-fitting.html) in section "Using Normalize or Center and Scale".

The `Normalize: 'on'` setting fails here (1) even with very narrow upper and lower limits. 
Is the `Normalize` option transparent for the user, or will I have to change my boundaries after enabling it?

For now I help my self by multiplying x and correct the coefficients in the fit results afterwards.

```
ScalingFactor = 1000;
[xData, yData] = prepareCurveData( myx * ScalingFactor, myy );
ft = fittype(..)
[fitresult, gof] = fit( xData, yData, ft, opts );
%% now correct the results
```

This does not look very elegant to me for a quite expensive software. 
4 years ago there was a [similar question on sx](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19812687/denormalize-results-of-curve-fit-on-normalized-data) without a handy solution.

Is there a better solution today?

1) Perhaps the error message helps other users to find this question/answer some day, so I paste it here:

```
Error using fit>iFit (line 340)
Complex value computed by model function, fitting cannot continue.
Try using or tightening upper and lower bounds on coefficients.
```

Answer (score 0):

You might consider placing the scaling factor inside the function itself as a fitted parameter.  For example, instead of:

```
scaledX = x * 1000
y = f(scaledX)
```

you would instead directly fit to:

```
y = f(scalingFactor * x)
```

so that the fitting (hopefully) finds the optimum scaling factor for you.

Comment: more variables make it worse.

Comment: This might be the initial parameters used by the nonlinear solver, set using x0 according to https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/fsolve.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com - just search for "x0".